# Remove Woocommerce message from Woocommerce Cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the Woocommerce Preorders plugin and on my cart page, it displays a message, "Your previous cart was emptied because pre-orders must be purchased separately." if a user adds the same item to their cart twice. (My site is getshru.com, and the cart page is getshru.com/preorder).

I've used the php answer (first answer) from this question to remove another unwanted woocommerce-message on the Cart page. However, I don't fully understand how it works so I can't quite get a version of this to work to remove this other unwanted message.
[Wordpress - Woocommerece remove "Added to Cart" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024405/wordpress-woocommerece-remove-added-to-cart-message)

Any recommendations? Thanks for any/all advice, I'm new to this.