# Hide Added to Cart message in Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I want to remove the **"xx product has been added to your cart"** message from the top of my checkout page.

How can I do that?

There was a suggestion by someone (link below), but it didn't work for me.

[Remove/Hide Woocommerce Added to Cart Message but Keep/Display Coupon Applied Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645095/remove-hide-woocommerce-added-to-cart-message-but-keep-display-coupon-applied-me/34657603#34657603)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update for Woocommerce 3+**

The hook `wc_add_to_cart_message` is deprecated and replaced by `wc_add_to_cart_message_html`. You can use the following (compact effective way):

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', '__return_false' );
```

Or the normal way:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'empty_wc_add_to_cart_message');
function empty_wc_add_to_cart_message( $message, $products ) { 
    return ''; 
};
```

---

Before Woocommerce 3, use this:

Removing only the message *(pasting it to your `function.php` file inside your active child theme or theme)*. This function will return an empty message:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'empty_wc_add_to_cart_message', 10, 2 );
function empty_wc_add_to_cart_message( $message, $product_id ) { 
    return ''; 
};
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Note: `wc_add_to_cart_message` replace deprecated hook `woocommerce_add_to_cart_message`.

*(UPDATED)*

**CSS: Removing top message box on checkout page** *(add this css rule to the `style.css` file located inside your active child theme or theme)*:

```css
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce .woocommerce-message {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This deleted the message & the button that said Continue Shopping, but it leaves an empty grey box at the top of the page. Is there a way to remove that?

Comment: I tried suggestion #2. The first one didn't work for me. The site link is https://sprinly.com/subscription-plan, then you click any of the sign up buttons, then go to https://sprinly.com/checkout. You will see the box at the top. Thanks you in advance!!

Comment: This worked great for me. I no longer see the grey box or the message. Thank you!

Comment: You may not need the function, but just the css rule… Thanks Mary.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Added CSS code but not PHP code (I have only `functions.php`).

Comment: @Primož'c0dehunter'Kralj The php code goes in function.php of your active child theme or active theme.

Comment: Where do I find this file? I can't find it under [current theme directory](http://imgur.com/a/PiV59).

Comment: @Primož'c0dehunter'Kralj It's inside your "optimizer" theme folder normally. Each theme has a function.php file (inside). Is better to set a child theme, because you don't loose your customizations when you update the parent theme… see [wordpress child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for that.

Comment: wc_add_to_cart_message is deprecated, use wc_add_to_cart_message_html instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this code in order to hide this

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', '__return_false' );
```

You can find more information here [hide added to your cart](https://www.techybois.com/wordpress/remove-product-has-been-added-to-your-cart)