# Remove add to cart notice and change "add to cart" button in Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

How to remove "has been added to your cart" text [image] from shopping cart page and how to replace quantity and add to cart button with custom button ( my image ) for it to look like this [image]

This is how it looks now: [image].

I used [Loic's css code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37126658/hide-added-to-cart-message-on-checkout-page-in-woocommerce) in my child style.css to remove text in cart page but it didn't work...

This is entire code in my child style.css file (Am I missing something):

```
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce .woocommerce-message {
display:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is multiple ways:

**1) Using PHP** *(the best way)*:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', '__return_false' );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

**2) Using CSS** *(**not recommended**: As it's on cart page, it will hide all other notices)*:

```css
.woocommerce-cart .woocommerce .woocommerce-message { 
    display:none !important;
}
```

Goes in styles.css file of your active child theme (or active theme).

---

To change add to cart button styling try this CSS rules:

```css
.button.alt.single_add_to_cart_button {
    background-color: #36ae33 !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Goes in styles.css file of your active child theme (or active theme).

You will have to add some other rules to change, font attributes and padding…

Answer (score 2):

You can place PHP snippets at the bottom of your child theme functions.php file (before "?>" if you have it).

REMOVE MESSAGE:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', '__return_null' );
```

EDIT MESSAGE:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html','msg_custom_add_to_cart_message' );
function msg_custom_add_to_cart_message() { 
global $woocommerce;
$return_to  = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'));
$message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forwards">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __('Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );
return $message;
}
```