# Remove Woocommerce add to cart message but keep updating cart amount

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using quick view pro by Barn2 for woocommerce and using this code to hide the add to cart message [Hide Added to Cart message in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37126658/hide-added-to-cart-message-in-woocommerce/37129366#37129366) which works fine, but in my case the cart amount is not updated until page refresh. So my question is how to modify the code so I be able to hide the message but allow the cart to be updated in the background without need of refresh? Thanks!

Comment: The problem comes from your plugin, and you should contact their support pages explaining your problem.

Comment: updating the cart without manually refreshing requires jquery.

Comment: Any coder that want to solve my issue ready to pay for it?

Comment: The plugin author redirected me to Codeable :) as it's custom work, they even don't offer plugin customization! I will appreciate if anyone wants to look at my issue and make the customization not for free ofcourse.