# WooCommerce - unset "<product> removed notice…" on cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, storefront

actions and filters. On my WooCommerce site I get the following message when I remove a product from the shopping cart:

```
"<product name>" removed. Undo?
```

Looking over WooCommerce source code I have found a conditional statement in `class-wc-form-header.php` as part of the function **`update_cart_action()`**:

```
$removed_notice .= ' <a href="' . esc_url( WC()->cart->get_undo_url( $cart_item_key ) ) . '">' . __( 'Undo?', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
```

But I can't find the way to use it for eliminate this notice.  I have try css solutions but it didn't work:

[image]

PS: that may not be the code snippet that is bothering me, but its the only one I have found that seems to make sense.

How can I remove this bothering notice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in different ways:

**1. Overriding the notices.php template:**
You have first *(if not done yet)* to copy woocommerce **`templates`** folder inside your active child theme or theme, then rename it **`woocommerce`**. Then open/edit  `notices/notices.php` and try to replace the code:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Show messages
 * ... Blabla ... / ... blabla ...
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( ! $messages ){
    return;
}

?>

<?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : // Change your template code from here
    if ( strpos( $message, 'removed' ) === false ) : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-info"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?></div>
<?php endif;
endforeach; ?>
```

**2. Using hooks:**

```php
function remove_added_to_cart_notice()
{
    $notices = WC()->session->get('wc_notices', array());

    foreach( $notices['notices'] as $key => &$notice){
        if( strpos( $notice, 'removed' ) !== false){
            $added_to_cart_key = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
    unset( $notices['notices'][$added_to_cart_key] );

    WC()->session->set('wc_notices', $notices);
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product','remove_added_to_cart_notice',1);
add_action('woocommerce_shortcode_before_product_cat_loop','remove_added_to_cart_notice',1);
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop','remove_added_to_cart_notice',1);
```

**3. Using CSS** (with something like):

```css
.woocommerce-cart .woocommerce-message {
    display: none !important;
}
```

References:

- [Wordpress - Woocommerece remove "Added to Cart" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024405/wordpress-woocommerece-remove-added-to-cart-message)
- [New wc-notice-functions.php on github](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-notice-functions.php)

Comment: They worked to perfection! Thank you so much, and also thank you for citing the proper way of editing the notices.php file by adding the directory to the child theme.

Comment: Note: As of woocommerece 3.3 the structure of notice array has been changed, check Robin B answer bellow for new syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change this to get it to work.  Specifically, the array field is singular **notice** or at least it is now.

```
$notices = WC()->session->get('wc_notices', array());
foreach( $notices['notice'] as $key => &$notice){
    if( strpos( $notice, 'whilst' ) !== false){ 
        $BadNotice_key = $key;
        unset( $notices['notice'][$BadNotice_key] );
        WC()->session->set('wc_notices', $notices);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update regarding **Overriding the notices.php template:**

```
<?php foreach ( $notices as $notice ) :
        if ( strpos( $notice['notice'], 'removed' ) === false ) : ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-message"<?php echo wc_get_notice_data_attr( $notice ); ?> role="alert">
            <?php echo wc_kses_notice( $notice['notice'] ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif;
    endforeach; ?>
```

Had to have add the 'notice' array key to the strpos method or it wasn't finding the "removed" string within the notice message.   Hope this helps others who were having issues attempting to use this template override method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple answer to this problem as there is a hook that you can plug onto.

```
// This line is to be added in the functions.php
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_removed_notice_type', '__return_null');
```

Answer (score -3):

**1.** Easy way: in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php`

**2.** remove/disable this line: `wc_add_notice( $removed_notice );` (line 523) like this

```
            if ( $product && $product->is_in_stock() && $product->has_enough_stock( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                $removed_notice  = sprintf( __( '%s removed.', 'woocommerce' ), $item_removed_title );
                $removed_notice .= ' <a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_cart_undo_url( $cart_item_key ) ) . '" class="restore-item">' . __( 'Undo?', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
            } else {
                 $removed_notice = sprintf( __( '%s removed.', 'woocommerce' ), $item_removed_title );
            }
             // wc_add_notice( $removed_notice );
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't edit the core plugin as you could lose your change if there is an update